# Access data from second external SQLite database in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

This is my project structure

[image: Project Structure]

I am able to access the default SQLite database `db.sqlite3` created by Django, by importing the models directly inside of my views files

Like - `from basic.models import table1`

Now, I have another Database called `UTF.db` which is created by someone else, and I want to access it's data and perform normal QuerySet operations on the retrieved data

The problem is I don't know how to import the tables inside that database, as they are not inside any model file inside my project as it's created by someone else

I tried adding the tables inside the `UTF.db` database to a `models.py` file by first adding it to the `settings.py` file like the following

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'otherdb':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'UTF.db',
    }
}
```

And then using the `inspectdb` command to add the tables to an existing `models.py` file

The command I tried out -
`python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

But, that just causes my models.py file to get emptied out

Does anyone know how this can be solved?

In the end, I wish to import the table data inside of my views files by importing the respective model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify specific database as specified in [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-inspectdb-database)

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=otherdb > your_app/models.py
```

Also if possible putting otherdb in a different App is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the second database to the first one and use it from within the first one. You can use tables from both databases in single sql query.
Here is the doc https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html.

```
attach database '/path/to/dbfile.sqlite' as db_remote;

select * 
from some_table
join db_remote.remote_table on ....

detach database db_remote;
```

Answer (score 0):

@sevdimali's answer works fine to create the new models from an existing database

Once that is done you need to use the command -

`python manage.py makemigrations`

To add the changes to the migrations folder

Then use the command

`python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

To add the new changes to your database

**Note**: Use --fake-initial to ignore the already created tables while adding your new tables (so that they don't get recreated)

If there are no pre-existing models you can use

`python manage.py migrate`

Just like you do it normally

---

Now while importing the Database model inside of your view you can write

`from Appname.models import Tablename`

Where Appname is the App in which you added your new models

And to access it's data

`qs=Tablename.objects.using('otherdb').all()`

**Note**: `otherdb` is the name of the external database specified in the `settings.py` file

Now you can access all of your data in a similar way!!